# What is the fee_used meaning? How to get it?

Tags: fee

Problem: The handling fee deducted from my account is `"fee": "2906481685620092"`,but the `fee_used` is `"fee_used": "3626624538723810"`, Which one should I believe, `fee` or `fee_used`? What is the `fee_used` meaning? How to get it?

link: https://astar.subscan.io/extrinsic/0x09754fd0064edf2228a3cc5e0a71db05674b1bba85570031bd823e813beb6cd6

```
Chain: ASTAR
Block Hash: 0xce29231bc5ca9b6ccdd464b6792ddd66bffd802237ffc21b858938ddd64f62a5
Block Number: 2444067
Hash: 0x09754fd0064edf2228a3cc5e0a71db05674b1bba85570031bd823e813beb6cd6
"fee": "2906481685620092",
"fee_used": "3626624538723810",
```